# Functions in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was playing around with functions and tried to create a new widget:

```
newWidget(Function onTap){
  return InkWell(
    ...
    onTap: () => onTap
  );
}
```

When tried to use it, I found that giving the onTap as `onTap: () => onTap,` and using it as `onTap: () => onTap(),` performed differently. And there's other ways to use the onTap property.

So what's the difference between:

`onTap: () => onTap`

`onTap: () => onTap()`

`onTap: onTap()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onTap: () => func
```

This one point the widget to func function and tells it run it when tapped. Like you give it the address of the function and tell it to go there in case someone taps.

```
onTap: () => func()
onTap: func()
```

These two basically do the same thing and give onTap property the value returned from the func(). These ones however, takes onTap to the address instead of pointing it to it. These will run immediately after build completes.

You can simply call `onTap: func` if you don't have to pass it any parameters.

Otherwise call `onTap: (param1, param2, ...) => func(param1, param2, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like:

```
onTap: funcationName //with out brackets
```